# Data Binding Error While live data passing to Label in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am new to C#... I getting live data from Modbus TCP using EasyModbus. I want to pass the live data to label using the binding method but I got error

Error
Cannot bind to the property or column Value on the Datasource. Parameter name:dataMember

My code:

```
modbusClient = new ModbusClient("192.168.0.5", 502);
modbusClient.Connect();
int[] ReadValues = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 1);
txt40001.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ReadValues[0], "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Register.cs

```
public class Register : INotifyPropertyChanged{
        private int _Value;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public int Value
        {
            get{return _Value;}
            set{
                if (_Value != value)
                {
                    _Value = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You added a Binding to the wrong object. `int[] ReadValues` is an array of integers. You probaably wanted to Bind an object of Type `Register`. You also need to add this Binding once (since it's not clear, reading the code, when this Binding is created).

Comment: I have live data from int[] readvalues... how to binding that data in the label can you help me...